# Close div when click outside the div with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Here is the thing with jquery when i want to close div when i click outside the div .

```
 $(document).on("click", function (e) {
        if (e.target.id != "user-login-top" && !$(e.target).closest("#user-login-wrapper").length) {
            $("#user-login-wrapper").removeClass("wide");
        }
    });
```

what's the equal thing in angular ?
the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zqdmny41/)

many thanks

Comment: use ng-show and ng-hide for this.

Comment: Do you got your answer? else I will put an answer..

Comment: please put your answer

Comment: ok.. I am putting a general example..

Comment: ok thx, waiting for u

Comment: I put my answer. This is general example. you can use this on your code..

Comment: I have updated my answer with fiddle link. you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Through implementing a customized directive, clicking outside the top menu will hide the right sidebar.

Check out this: http://jsfiddle.net/zqdmny41/20/

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    // Add a function to hide the right sidebar.
    $scope.hideSideMenu = function() {
        $scope.bodyCon = false;
        $scope.noneStyle = false;
    }
    ...
})
.directive("outsideClick", ['$document', function( $document){
return {
    link: function( $scope, $element, $attributes ){
        var scopeExpression = $attributes.outsideClick,
            onDocumentClick = function(event){
                if(event.target.id != 'rightMenu' && event.target.id != 'toggle-menu') {
                    $scope.$apply(scopeExpression);
                }
            };

        $document.on("click", onDocumentClick);

        $element.on('$destroy', function() {
            $document.off("click", onDocumentClick);
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

In your HTML:

```
<aside class="rightbar" id="rightMenu" ng-class="{'noneStyle' : noneStyle}" outside-click="hideSideMenu()">
```

The effect is:

- clicking on the top icon will toggle the right sidebar,
- clicking on the right sidebar itself will trigger nothing,
- and clicking on somewhere else will hide the right sidebar.

The basic logic is:

- Create a customized directive named "outsideClick" and apply it to the right sidebar menu by adding an attribute `outside-click="hideSideMenu()"`
- The function name `hideSideMenu` is passed in to the directive, which adds an `click` event to the document.
- When user clicks to the document, if the target id is not `rightMenu` and not `toggle-menu`, the right sidebar will be hidden.

Reference: http://vadimpopa.com/onblur-like-for-a-div-in-angularjs-to-close-a-popup/

Comment: thank you, but it's close when i click on menu links ?!!

Comment: Last week I was on a rush, leaving the basic implementation logic only. Please checkout my updated answer.